# Belong and Own as transitive or intransitive verb

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, passive-voice, do-support, transitivity

I learned that Belong and Own are Intransitive verbs, hence they cannot be used in passive voice. If we use these sentences with is/was they become passive. But can we use this construction to tell someone's status?

Example 1

Is this property belong to my father? (Question)

Yes, this property is belong to your father (Answer)

Or

Example 2
Is this property owned by my father? (Question)

Yes, this property is owned by your father (Answer)

Are both my examples correct?

Can we use **belong** and **own** as stative verbs?

Comment: "this property is belong to your father" is **not** grammatical. "this property belongs to your father" is fine. You are probably confused because in question, you used 'is'. It's actually 'does' - does this property belong to my father? Yes, it does!

Comment: Do you want to know about transitive-intransitive verbs and/or stative-action verbs?

Comment: Try to clear up your question to help yourself. If you're asking about passive, write the past participle correctly (of the verb belong), or as @MaulikV writes, if you're using active, you will need "does". Lastly, I'm not sure what you are asking in your question: are the two verbs (in)transitive, or are your examples correct.

Answer (score 2):

"Own" is transitive, and takes a *Direct Object*:

- X owns Y

"Belong" is intransitive, and takes an *Indirect Object (or none at all)*:

- A belongs **to** B
- C does not belong here

As for your examples:  in Example 1, neither the question nor the answer is in correct form. They should be;

Q: **Does** this property belong to my father?

A: Yes, this property **belongs** to yout father.

(Neither of these is in *passive voice*. They can't be, because "belong" is *intransitive*.)

in Example 2, both the question and the answer are formed correctly. Both are in *passive voice*, which is possible because "own" is *transitive*.

Your last query, about whether "belong" and "own" *can be used* as stative verbs, has nothing to do with your examples or with the title of your Question.

If I understand correctly, both "own" and "belong" **are** stative verbs, no matter how you use them, but the *stative/active* distinction is independent of the *transitive/ intransitive* distinction.